# How to convert Angular 2/4 Reactive Forms custom validation Promise snippet to Observable pattern?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable, angular-reactive-forms

I found this reactive forms custom validation snippet where in it adds `emailIsTaken: true` after 1500ms in the errors object of the `emailAddress` formControl whenever the user types ***test@y.c***

[image]

```
takenEmailAddress(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (control.value === 'test@y.c') {
        resolve({'emailIsTaken': true});
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    }, 1500);
  });

  return promise;
}
```

I love the way observables solve development and readablity issues. As I read, benefits are immense. How can I convert something like this to observable pattern?

An Observable pattern that will add `emailIsTaken: true` to the errors object of the `emailAddress` formControl whenever the user types ***test@y.c***

[image: How am i going to add <code>emailIsTaken: true</code> inside errors object?]

And what is the counterpart of `resolve` and `reject` in observable pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The FormControl class has members ValueChanges and StatusChanges, which both return Observables and you can use that directly on your FormControl.

Something like this might work:

```
email: FormControl;
emailTaken: bool;

ngOnInit() {

    this.email.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        if (value === 'testy@y.c")
            this.emailTaken = true;
        else
            this.emailTaken = false;
        },
        error => //Handle error here
    );
}
```

This might not be the best solution, but it might give you an idea. Any time the value changes in the FormControl it will be checked for validity.

Note: This example will not work asynchronously.

You can also create an observable directly from a promise:

```
const observable = Observable.fromPromise(takenEmailAddress(control));
observable.subscribe(value => /*Do something to handle the value*/ ,
                     err => /*Handle the error*/
```

Comment: you snippet isn't adding anything to the error object of the formControl

Comment: Check my edit, I believe this is how it works, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the error object I'm referring to